# Why does this website freeze in IE 7 but not in any other browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, freeze

I built a Parts Catalog for a company recently. It works perfectly in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, etc.

However, in IE 7, every single page works except for the actual parts page itself: http://www.swstruckbodiesandtrailers.com/index.php?pageId=69

It actually locks the entire browser up, and after reviewing the source, I have no idea why.

Does anyone have any insight? It's merely simple HTML, CSS, and a few lines of jQuery--nothing out of the ordinary.

I've never encountered a page that froze the entire browser before.

Comment: Thanks for checking. I guess it's an IE-specific problem regardless of the version then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I isolated the offensive code to this:

```
<div class='partsLevel1'> 
  <h3><span class='floatLeft'>Box Parts (0)</h3> 
</div>
```

Clearly this is a simple blunder on my part by forgetting to close the `<span>` tag. I've quite surprised this actually freezes IE though. That doesn't seem like a very graceful failure on their part.

It looks like when IE gets multiple floated elements that remain unclosed, it just locks up entirely.

And the reason I have a seemingly unnecessary `<span>` inside of a `<h3>` element is because when you're logged in, there are a few administrative links that are floated right.

Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: Looks like it could have been caught with an XML validation pass.

Answer (score 5):

You need to cut down the site piece by piece and isolate the exact cause of the lock up.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that there is an AJAX call that is not getting to the correct ReadyState for some reason.

Comment: There is no AJAX happening during the page load. The only AJAX call is when the Login link at the bottom of the page is clicked.

Comment: As AJAX calls are (usually, by design) asynchronous, they just wouldn't lock a browser. The only thing that would happen is that the `onreadystatechange` event listener will not be called for a long time, at least not with `readyState==4`.

Comment: I think that you're assuming implementation... It could be a Do loop checking the readystate on the xmlhttp object which could, in fact, lock the browser.  Irrelevant at this point as it appears the problem has been solved.

Comment: That's true, but when would you write a `do` loop doing that? I really wonder this, could you give a short explanation?

Comment: I'm just thinking of a naive, synchronous implementation.  It's stuck in my head simply because I had a developer at my last job write code like that that locked up a site in Safari b/c the readystate sequence is a little different than in other browsers.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about that. You mean issues like on http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/09/xmlhttp_notes_r_2.html ?